# Resistance and voltage drop conclusion

Tags: voltage, resistance

Is it true that the higher the resistance the higher voltage would drop?

Comment: Generally, in a circuit where  the current travels through two or more resistances, increasing one R in isolation will increase V across it.

Answer (score 3):

No. This is only true if the current stays the same.

Imagine a single resistor across a battery. Regardless of the battery voltage and the resistor value, the resistor has to drop all that voltage.

[image]

Now a imagine a constant current source instead of the battery. Now the higher the resistor the higher the voltage drop because the current source forces more power through the same resistor as R increases.

[image]